# Linear least squares in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ with three data points.

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

Given data points in the form $(x,y,f(x,y)) = (1,1,7),(1,3,0),(1,-1,8)$, find the least squares solution $\hat x$ to the system of equations $Ax=b$.

Is there enough information to use least squares? The solution created $A$ using the $x$ and $y$ coordinates and $b$ using $f(x,y)$. I do not understand  this problem. How can you solve for $\hat x$ when you do not know anything about the function? Isn't it presumptuous to assume a linear relationship?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you got enough information to construct the projection matrix $H$,
   $$
   H=X(X'X)^{-1}X',
   $$
   where 
   $
   X=\begin{pmatrix}
   1,\,\, 1\\
   1,\,\, 3\\
   1,-1
   \end{pmatrix}
   $,
   then $Hy=\hat{y}$ where $y=(7,0,8)'$, gives you the least square solution which is $(5,1,9)'$.
2. You do not necessarily assume linear relationship between $y$ and $x$, you may view the least square solution as a linear approximation of $f(y,x)$ based on $x$. So, basically your assumption is of more technical nature like estimability of the linear (affine) approximation of $y$ using $x$.

Answer (score 0):

We are given a sequence of measurements $\left\{ x_{k}, y_{k}, f_{k} \right\}_{k=1}^{3}$. Generally, we could hope to find three fit parameters, a trial function like
$$
  f(x,y) = c_{0}g_{0}(x,y) + c_{1}g_{1}(x,y) + c_{2}g_{2}(x,y)
$$
where the functions $g$ are linearly independent.

You asked about the linear case where
$$
 f(x,y) = c_{0} + c_{1}x + c_{2}y.
$$
That problem looks like this
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} c &= F \\[5pt]
%
  \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
       1 & x_{1} & y_{1} \\
       1 & x_{2} & y_{2} \\
       1 & x_{3} & y_{3} 
    \end{array}
  \right]
  \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
       c_{0} \\
       c_{1} \\
       c_{2} 
    \end{array}
  \right]
&=
  \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
       f_{1} \\
       f_{2} \\
       f_{3} 
    \end{array}
  \right] \\[5pt]
%
  \left[
    \begin{array}{ccr}
       1 & 1 &  1 \\
       1 & 1 &  3 \\
       1 & 1 & -1 
    \end{array}
  \right]
  \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
       c_{0} \\
       c_{1} \\
       c_{2} 
    \end{array}
  \right]
&=
  \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
       7 \\
       0 \\
       7 
    \end{array}
  \right] 
\end{align}
$$
The is no solution vector $c$ which satisfies this equation, so instead of asking that $\mathbf{A}c-F = 0$, we ask instead that $\mathbf{A}c-F$ be as small as possible.To measure length, we must select a norm, and the choice here is the $2-$norm of least squares.

The least squares solution is
$$
  c_{LS} = \mathbf{A}^{\dagger}F + \left(\mathbf{I}_{3} - \mathbf{A}^{\dagger}\mathbf{A} \right) y, \quad y\in\mathbb{C}^{3}
$$

There is a problem with this model in that the first two column vectors of $\mathbf{A}$ are identical. This matrix has rank $\rho = 2.$ We can't use the normal equations.

Using the SVD, 
$$
 \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} = \frac{1}{24}
\left[
\begin{array}{ccr}
 4 & 1 & 7 \\
 4 & 1 & 7 \\
 0 & 6 & -6 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
and the full solution is
$$
  c_{LS} = \frac{1}{24}
  \left[
    \begin{array}{r}
       77 \\
       77 \\
       -42 
    \end{array}
  \right]
+ \alpha
  \left[
    \begin{array}{r}
      -1 \\
       1 \\
       0 
    \end{array}
  \right].
$$

The least squares fit is the best fit, but it may not be a good fit. That is, given the trial function, the method will find the best parameters. But the trial function may be bad.

The residual error vector
$$
 r(c_{LS}) = \frac{1}{6}
  \left[
    \begin{array}{r}
      -14 \\
       7 \\
       7 
    \end{array}
  \right].
$$
The total error is $r\cdot r = \frac{49}{6} \approx 8.2.$